# Trying to determine CC number and select type

Tags: javascript, html, credit-card

I am working on an assignment where I have to write the JS that will read in a credit card number and then select the appropriate checkbox for whichever type of card it is (visa, amex, discover, mastercard).

The HTML was pre-written I just had to write the JS.

You're supposed to be able to type a number and tab over and it auto-select the type but instead I keep getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: discover is not a function"

I have never encountered this, can anyone enlighten me?

```js
"use strict";

function selectCardType() {
    var cardNumValue = document.getElementById("ccNum").value;
    var visa = /^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/;
    var mc = /^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/;
    var discover = /^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$/;
    var amex = /^3[47][0-9]{13}$/;

    if (visa.test(cardNumValue)) {
        document.getElementById("visa").checked = "checked";
    } else if (mc.test(cardNumValue)) {
        document.getElementById("mc").checked = "checked";
    } else if (discover(cardNumValue)) {
        document.getElementById("discover").checked = "checked";
    } else if (amex(cardNumValue)) {
        document.getElementById("amex").checked = "checked";
    }
}

function createEventListeners() {
    var cardNum = document.getElementById("ccNum");
    if (cardNum.addEventListener) {
        cardNum.addEventListener("change", selectCardType, false);
    } else if (cardNum.attachEvent) {
        cardNum.attachEvent("onchange", selectCardType);
 }
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", createEventListeners, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", createEventListeners);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=page-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Hands-on Project 8-3</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
   <script src="modernizr.custom.65897.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <article>
      <form action="results.htm">
         <fieldset id="paymentInfo" class="text">
            <legend>Payment Information</legend>
            <div class="offset">
               <label for="ccNum">Card #</label>
               <input id="ccNum" name="CardNumber" type="number" required="required" />
               <div id="ccNumErrorMessage"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="cards" class="inline">
               <input id="visa" name="PaymentType" type="radio" value="Visa" />
               <label for="visa">Visa</label>
               <input id="mc" name="PaymentType" type="radio" value="MC" />
               <label for="mc">Master Card</label>
               <input id="discover" name="PaymentType" type="radio" value="Discover" />
               <label for="discover">Discover</label>
               <input id="amex" name="PaymentType" type="radio" value="AmEx" />
               <label for="amex">American Express</label>
            </div>
            <div class="offset">
               <label>Expiration</label>
               <div class="inline" id="exp">
                  <label for="expMo" id="expMoLabel">Expiration Month</label>
                  <select id="expMo" name="ExpMonth" required="required">
                     <option value="01">01</option>
                     <option value="02">02</option>
                     <option value="03">03</option>
                     <option value="04">04</option>
                     <option value="05">05</option>
                     <option value="06">06</option>
                     <option value="07">07</option>
                     <option value="08">08</option>
                     <option value="09">09</option>
                     <option value="10">10</option>
                     <option value="11">11</option>
                     <option value="12">12</option>
                  </select>
                  <label for="expYr" id="expYrLabel">Expiration Year</label>
                  <select id="expYr" name="ExpYear" required="required">
                     <option value="2017">2017</option>
                     <option value="2018">2018</option>
                     <option value="2019">2019</option>
                     <option value="2020">2020</option>
                     <option value="2021">2021</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
               <input id="cvv" name="CVVValue" type="number" required="required" /> 
            </div>
         </fieldset>
      </form>
   </article>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is it you can write `visa.test()` and `mc.test()`, but not figure out that you wrote `discover()` and `amex()`? Did you read the code **you** wrote?

Comment: Yes...multiple times.  Sorry if this is annoying for you, I am just learning JavaScript and I've been working on it for hours today.  Now that you point it out it is absurdly obvious. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielMiller it's okay, sometimes you just need an extra set of eyes. Keep it up!

Comment: @AndyGaskell thank you!  I appreciate it.